# Debian server with high cpu usage

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, cpu-usage

I have a map server with Geoserver on a Debian in which I have OpenJDK 8, Tomcat 9 and Elasticsearch installed but from time to time this server hangs due to excessive use of CPU.

I have reviewed the logs; I have limited the use of CPU and memory for both Tomcat and Java but the problem of excessive CPU usage continues to occur from time to time.

The Debian server is virtualized on VMWare; Debian server hangs and does not respond to SSH access and when I enter the VMWare admin console I see a red alert about CPU usage.

Comment: *"server hangs due to excessive use of cpu"* - either it's a HW issue (overheating, faulty CPU) or I have serious doubts about this statement. The only way to "overload" the CPU is to run tens of thousands of processes all eating the CPU, e.g. a fork bomb. The last time I had CPU "overloaded" was with Windows 98SE (over 25 years ago) which is not a true multitasking OS. Please explain how and why you've decided that the CPU is "overloaded".

Comment: The Debian server is virtualized on Vmware; Debian server hangs and does not respond to ssh access and when I enter the VMware admin console I see a red alert about CPU usage